# rallycombobox widget is missing entries in the dropdown

Tags: extjs, sdk, rally

The app makes a release combobox (which works nicely). Then app generates testset combox based on selected release.

What i see right now is that'testset' rallycombobox always contain one entry only... even though i expect 3-4 entries.
In console logs i can see that the filtered testset record is correct (correct number of testsets). But the testset dropdown UI only shows one entry. Does anyone know why? Thanks!

```
Ext.define('CustomApp', {
extend: 'Rally.app.App',
componentCls: 'app',

launch: function() {
    this._createReleaseComboBoxe();
},

//A)make a release combobox
_createReleaseComboBoxe: function(){

    //this container would contain release and testset dropdown boxes.
    this.comboboxContainer = Ext.create('Ext.container.Container',{
        layout : {
            type:'hbox',
            align:'stretch'
        }
    });


    this.releaseComboBox = Ext.widget('rallyreleasecombobox',{
         width: 250,
        autoSelect: true,
        listeners: {
            ready: function(combobox){
                console.log('selected release ',this.releaseComboBox.getRecord().get('Name'));
                this._createTestSetComboBox();
            },
            select: function(combobox){
                console.log('selected release ',this.releaseComboBox.getRecord().get('Name'));
                this._createTestSetComboBox();
            },
            scope: this
        }
    });

    this.comboboxContainer.add(this.releaseComboBox);
    this.add(this.comboboxContainer);

},


//B)make a testset drop down - filtered by selected release

//B1) make a store
_createTestSetComboBox: function(){

    if(this.testsetbox){
        this.comboboxContainer.remove(this.testsetbox);
    }

    this.testsetbox = Ext.widget('rallycombobox', {
        width: 250,
        storeConfig: {
            autoLoad: true,
            model: 'TestSet',
            filters:[{
                property: 'Release',
                operator: '=',
                value: this.releaseComboBox.getRecord().get('_ref')
            }]
        },
        listeners: {
            ready: function(combobox){
                console.log('total number of testsets found: ',this.testsetbox.getStore().getTotalCount());
                this.testsetbox.getStore().each(function(record){
                    console.log(record.get('Name'));
                });


                // this._else();
            },
            select: function(combobox){
                console.log('total number of testsets found: ',this.testsetbox.getStore().getTotalCount());
                this.testsetbox.getStore().each(function(record){
                    console.log(record.get('Name'));
                });

            },
            scope: this
        }
    });

    this.comboboxContainer.add(this.testsetbox);
}


});
```

HTTP GET request that is being sent:

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/TestSet?start=1&pagesize=200&query=(Release%20%3D%20%22%2Frelease%2F61143217251%22)&fetch=ObjectID%2CObjectUUID%2CVersionId%2CDescription%2CDisplayColor%2CExpedite%2CFormattedID%2CLatestDiscussionAgeInMinutes%2CName%2CNotes%2CReady%2CScheduleState%2CScheduleStatePrefix%2CTaskActualTotal%2CTaskEstimateTotal%2CTaskRemainingTotal%2CBlocked%2CBlockedReason%2CDefectStatus%2CDragAndDropRank%2CLastBuild%2CPassingTestCaseCount%2CPlanEstimate%2CTaskStatus%2CTestCaseCount%2CTestCaseStatus%2CCreationDate%2CSubscription%2CWorkspace%2CLastUpdateDate%2COwner%2CProject%2CRevisionHistory%2CAcceptedDate%2CBlocker%2CIteration%2CLastRun%2CRelease&includePermissions=true&compact=true&project=%2Fproject%2F12148936254&projectScopeUp=false&projectScopeDown=true
```

here is the response i see in network traffic. (i see some weird chars in there):

{"QueryResult": {"TotalResultCount": 2, "StartIndex": 1, "PageSize": 200, "Results": [{"_ref": "/testset/62681964594", "_refObjectUUID": "253b02c2-0018-4ea1-9c5b-04b23e83c73f", "_refObjectName": "xxxx", "_p": "7", "CreationDate": "2016-09-09T15:57:28.479Z", "_CreatedAt": "Sep 9, 2016", "ObjectID": 62681964594, "ObjectUUID": "253b02c2-0018-4ea1-9c5b-04b23e83c73f", "VersionId": "1901", "Subscription": {"_ref": "/subscription/183584369", "_refObjectUUID": "55f700e3-c985-44d2-b855-f39de255bd25", "_refObjectName": "xxxx xxxx, Inc. - xxxx", "_p": "7", "CreationDate": "2008-09-02T18:57:01.000Z", "_CreatedAt": "Sep 2, 2008", "ObjectID": 183584369, "ObjectUUID": "55f700e3-c985-44d2-b855-f39de255bd25", "VersionId": "51", "Name": "xxxx xxxx, Inc. - xxxx", "_type": "Subscription"}, "Workspace": {"_ref": "/workspace/11012665496", "_refObjectUUID": "74d703e2-8386-48a8-8a9e-3f4163be0870", "_refObjectName": "xxxx", "_p": "0", "CreationDate": "2013-03-18T19:15:46.626Z", "_CreatedAt": "Mar 18, 2013", "ObjectID": 11012665496, "ObjectUUID": "74d703e2-8386-48a8-8a9e-3f4163be0870", "VersionId": "11", "Subscription": {"_ref": "/subscription/183584369"}, "Description": "xxxx", "Name": "xxxx", "Notes": "", "Owner": {"_ref": "/user/183584660", "_refObjectUUID": "54cd9208-3337-4d5f-ae18-f006d563d03c", "_refObjectName": "Amy Ulug", "_p": "0", "ObjectID": 183584660, "_type": "User"}, "_type": "Workspace"}, "Description": "", "DisplayColor": "#848689", "Expedite": false, "FormattedID": "TS841", "LastUpdateDate": "2017-01-24T21:57:26.349Z", "LatestDiscussionAgeInMinutes": null, "Name": "xxxx", "Notes": "", "Owner": null, "Project": {"_ref": "/project/12148936254", "_refObjectUUID": "dfae7c8c-3d31-43b6-b80f-d29e30fa18dd", "_refObjectName": "NII", "_p": "0", "CreationDate": "2013-05-30T08:31:47.313Z", "_CreatedAt": "May 30, 2013", "ObjectID": 12148936254, "ObjectUUID": "dfae7c8c-3d31-43b6-b80f-d29e30fa18dd", "VersionId": "60", "Subscription": {"_ref": "/subscription/183584369"}, "Description": "(was NAR)", "Name": "NII", "Notes": "", "Owner": {"_ref": "/user/183584660"}, "RevisionHistory": {"_ref": "/revisionhistory/12148936255", "_refObjectUUID": "cdc6c0fa-418a-402e-b495-22f10d12483f", "_p": "7", "CreationDate": "2013-05-30T08:31:47.313Z", "_CreatedAt": "May 30, 2013", "ObjectID": 12148936255, "ObjectUUID": "cdc6c0fa-418a-402e-b495-22f10d12483f", "VersionId": "1", "Subscription": {"_ref": "/subscription/183584369"}, "Workspace": {"_ref": "/workspace/11012665496"}, "_type": "RevisionHistory"}, "Workspace": {"_ref": "/workspace/11012665496"}, "_type": "Project"}, "Ready": false, "RevisionHistory": {"_ref": "/revisionhistory/62681964605", "_refObjectUUID": "ce39b25d-9831-4930-a112-abb80cec0631", "_p": "7", "CreationDate": "2016-09-09T15:57:28.479Z", "_CreatedAt": "Sep 9, 2016", "ObjectID": 62681964605, "ObjectUUID": "ce39b25d-9831-4930-a112-abb80cec0631", "VersionId": "1", "Subscription": {"_ref": "/subscription/183584369"}, "Workspace": {"_ref": "/workspace/11012665496"}, "_type": "RevisionHistory"}, "AcceptedDate": null, "Blocker": null, "ScheduleState": "In-Progress", "ScheduleStatePrefix": "P", "TaskActualTotal": 0.0, "TaskEstimateTotal": 0.0, "TaskRemainingTotal": 0.0, "Blocked": false, "BlockedReason": null, "DefectStatus": "SOME_CLOSED", "DragAndDropRank": ",~g}7%@{P]?S??{S!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!", "Iteration": {"_ref": "/iteration/61479322083", "_refObjectUUID": "a6ccc8a6-20b8-4789-8166-a01c34c29a7b", "_refObjectName": "Pre-PI14 IP", "_p": "7", "CreationDate": "2016-08-22T20:59:46.660Z", "_CreatedAt": "Aug 22, 2016", "ObjectID": 61479322083, "ObjectUUID": "a6ccc8a6-20b8-4789-8166-a01c34c29a7b", "VersionId": "1", "Subscription": {"_ref": "/subscription/183584369"}, "Workspace": {"_ref": "/workspace/11012665496"}, "Name": "Pre-PI14 IP", "Notes": "", "PlanEstimate": 7.0, "Project": {"_ref": "/project/12148936254"}, "RevisionHistory": {"_ref": "/revisionhistory/61479322085", "_refObjectUUID": "0ecbd8a8-b4ba-4cc7-8ea1-0e4b863e1ddd", "_p": "7", "CreationDate": "2016-08-22T20:59:46.661Z", "_CreatedAt": "Aug 22, 2016", "ObjectID": 61479322085, "ObjectUUID": "0ecbd8a8-b4ba-4cc7-8ea1-0e4b863e1ddd", "VersionId": "1", "Subscription": {"_ref": "/subscription/183584369"}, "Workspace": {"_ref": "/workspace/11012665496"}, "_type": "RevisionHistory"}, "TaskActualTotal": 0.0, "TaskEstimateTotal": 15.0, "TaskRemainingTotal": 0.0, "_type": "Iteration"}, "LastBuild": "RC4", "LastRun": "2016-12-06T09:00:00.000Z", "PassingTestCaseCount": 490, "PlanEstimate": null, "Release": {"_ref": "/release/51258917569", "_refObjectUUID": "fab69c95-af3d-4299-80c6-6eee63922afd", "_refObjectName": "xxxx", "_p": "7", "CreationDate": "2016-02-12T19:40:05.721Z", "_CreatedAt": "Feb 12, 2016", "ObjectID": 51258917569, "ObjectUUID": "fab69c95-af3d-4299-80c6-6eee63922afd", "VersionId": "6", "Subscription": {"_ref": "/subscription/183584369"}, "Workspace": {"_ref": "/workspace/11012665496"}, "Name": "xxxx", "Notes": "$$$#2016-12-28#PI_14 data #0-4-12-4-20-400-416-0-1-0-0-1-0-20-0-5-12-4-21-400-436##11615-11702-11995-12128#9623-10346-10378-10685-10725-10726-11537-11586-11589-11592-11595-11608#10403-10412-10575-10715##11827###***$$$#2017-1-9#NII1.10#0-4-11-4-19-380-396-0-1-1-0-2-0-30-0-5-12-4-21-380-426##11615-11702-11995-12128#9623-10346-10378-10685-10725-10726-11586-11589-11592-11595-11608#10403-10412-10575-10715##11827#11537##***", "PlanEstimate": 101.5, "Project": {"_ref": "/project/12148936254"}, "RevisionHistory": {"_ref": "/revisionhistory/51258917571", "_refObjectUUID": "e6c06886-87a5-4085-b3a3-e3711fbc762f", "_p": "7", "CreationDate": "2016-02-12T19:40:05.723Z", "_CreatedAt": "Feb 12, 2016", "ObjectID": 51258917571, "ObjectUUID": "e6c06886-87a5-4085-b3a3-e3711fbc762f", "VersionId": "1", "Subscription": {"_ref": "/subscription/183584369"}, "Workspace": {"_ref": "/workspace/11012665496"}, "_type": "RevisionHistory"}, "TaskActualTotal": 130.0, "TaskEstimateTotal": 1339.0, "TaskRemainingTotal": 137.0, "_type": "Release"}, "TaskStatus": "NONE", "TestCaseCount": 637, "TestCaseStatus": "ALL_RUN_SOME_NOT_PASSING", "_type": "TestSet"}, {"_ref": "/testset/62682068436", "_refObjectUUID": "cba56f1f-6631-462b-8329-fa1320310f10", "_refObjectName": "xxxx", "_p": "7", "CreationDate": "2016-09-09T15:58:03.873Z", "_CreatedAt": "Sep 9, 2016", "ObjectID": 62682068436, "ObjectUUID": "cba56f1f-6631-462b-8329-fa1320310f10", "VersionId": "1904", "Subscription": {"_ref": "/subscription/183584369"}, "Workspace": {"_ref": "/workspace/11012665496"}, "Description": "", "DisplayColor": "#848689", "Expedite": false, "FormattedID": "TS842", "LastUpdateDate": "2017-01-27T07:45:26.507Z", "LatestDiscussionAgeInMinutes": null, "Name": "xxxx", "Notes": "", "Owner": null, "Project": {"_ref": "/project/12148936254"}, "Ready": false, "RevisionHistory": {"_ref": "/revisionhistory/62682068438", "_refObjectUUID": "69e21793-be97-4b5a-88bc-8ea3755fc732", "_p": "7", "CreationDate": "2016-09-09T15:58:03.874Z", "_CreatedAt": "Sep 9, 2016", "ObjectID": 62682068438, "ObjectUUID": "69e21793-be97-4b5a-88bc-8ea3755fc732", "VersionId": "1", "Subscription": {"_ref": "/subscription/183584369"}, "Workspace": {"_ref": "/workspace/11012665496"}, "_type": "RevisionHistory"}, "AcceptedDate": null, "Blocker": null, "ScheduleState": "In-Progress", "ScheduleStatePrefix": "P", "TaskActualTotal": 0.0, "TaskEstimateTotal": 0.0, "TaskRemainingTotal": 0.0, "Blocked": false, "BlockedReason": null, "DefectStatus": "SOME_CLOSED", "DragAndDropRank": ",~fjfT@{P]?S??{S!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!", "Iteration": {"_ref": "/iteration/61479322083"}, "LastBuild": "RC4", "LastRun": "2016-11-29T19:01:00.000Z", "PassingTestCaseCount": 351, "PlanEstimate": null, "Release": {"_ref": "/release/51258917569"}, "TaskStatus": "NONE", "TestCaseCount": 616, "TestCaseStatus": "ALL_RUN_SOME_NOT_PASSING", "_type": "TestSet"}]}}

Comment: hmm, that's very strange.  so your console logs print out 4 items, but when you expand the dropdown there's only 1?  can you inspect your network traffic in the developer console?  i'm wondering what the request to the testset endpoint looks like.  and if it's making another additional request when you first open it that might have some extra filters on it or something that may be causing you to miss data...

Comment: i added the response i see in traffic. please note that i have replace sensitive info with 'xxxx'. I see both testsets in there but there are also some weird chars in the response.

Comment: Json parser cannot parse this response...

Comment: DragAndDropRank object looks bad.

Comment: i copy/pasted it into a json parser/validator online and it parsed just fine.  is it possible the malformed characters were in the part you blocked out?

Comment: i checked the suppressed data. it looks fine and it doesnt invalidate json. And there is only one GET request being sent. i added it in the question.

Comment: Any other idea abt this? I m kinda stuck. Is there some other dropdown object i can try instead?

Comment: i'm pretty stumped here.  maybe this one?  https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.1/doc/#!/api/Rally.ui.combobox.ArtifactSearchComboBox

Comment: I figured out the issue. sort of... if i use <script type="text/javascript" src="/apps/2.0rc1/sdk.js"></script> then drop down works. seems like <script type="text/javascript" src="/apps/2.1/sdk.js"></script> doesnt work. can u please check.

Comment: @KyleMorse please check out my previous comment. I am able to see correct behaviour when using 2.0rc1 sdk version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I played around with your example and updated it a little bit- this seems to work for me:

```
Ext.define('CustomApp', {
    extend: 'Rally.app.TimeboxScopedApp',
    componentCls: 'app',

    scopeType: 'release',

    onScopeChange: function(scope) {
        this._createTestSetComboBox();
    },

    _createTestSetComboBox: function () {

        if (this.testsetbox) {
            this.testsetbox.destroy();
        }

        this.testsetbox = this.add({
            xtype: 'rallyartifactsearchcombobox',
            width: 250,
            allowNoEntry: false,
            allowClear: false,
            storeConfig: {
                models: ['testset'],
                filters: [this.getContext().getTimeboxScope().getQueryFilter()]
            },
            listeners: {
                ready: function (combobox) {
                    console.log('total number of testsets found: ', this.testsetbox.getStore().getTotalCount());
                    this.testsetbox.getStore().each(function (record) {
                        console.log(record.get('Name'));
                    });


                    // this._else();
                },
                select: function (combobox) {
                    console.log('total number of testsets found: ', this.testsetbox.getStore().getTotalCount());
                    this.testsetbox.getStore().each(function (record) {
                        console.log(record.get('Name'));
                    });

                },
                scope: this
            }
        });
    }
});
```

The main change is that I updated your app to use the TimeboxScopedApp to deal with the release picker for you automatically.  And I am using the ArtifactSearchComboBox rather than just a standard ComboBox.  It feels like there was a subtle bug in what you were doing- I'm just not sure what it was.

Mind giving this a shot?  This would be preferable to downgrading the sdk version to 2.0rc1 since that is a very early preview release and is considered unsupported at this point.

Comment: Thanks. yes it works. i will use this work around then.

Comment: great.  glad to hear it.  sorry it took so long for me to actually try to create a workaround for you.  happy hacking!

Comment: I find Sencha framework very confusing. I kinda hate it. lol.

Comment: us too.  hopefully we're going to get a new react based sdk together sometime in the next year.  stay tuned!